# Express Router: everything route that allows new routes

Tags: node.js, express, routes

Since express evaluates routes in the order they were added, you should put the more specific routes first.

```
server.get('/product/:id', router.getProduct);
server.get('/user/:id', router.getUser);
server.get('*', router.notFound);
```

However, the administrative side of the site needs to be able to create new sections. When a new section is created it is added to the Database, and then a new route is created. However, the `*` route captures everything and was added before the new section route. Thus, the new section route never matches.

If I remove the `*` route, then the new section routes do match. My question is how to create a route the matches on 404 requests, without using the `*` route. Or is there a way to add a route that always matches at the end of the routing matching order?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: How are section URL's named? Or is that completely arbitrary?

Comment: well, it would have to be up to the admin, so yeah, they can enter anything they like. at least that is the idea. perhaps the solution is to reconfigure how routes are named?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since sections can have arbitrary names, you could check for the validity of them in the catch-all handler. It would depend on how exactly your code is set up, but to give an idea:

```
server.get('/product/:id', router.getProduct);
server.get('/user/:id', router.getUser);
server.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
  let sectionName = req.url.substring(1);
  Sections.findByName(sectionName, (err, section) {
    // Pass errors to the generic error handler.
    if (err) return next(err);

    // If the section isn't known, pass it along.
    if (! section) return next();

    // Perform the section code here.
    ...
  });
});
server.use(router.notFound);
```

In other words: the `get('*')` route would take the path of the request, remove the leading slash (unless that's part of the section name), look it up in the database, and handle errors or unknown section names.

The final handler will generate a 404 for requests that fell through the section handler.

Answer (score -1):

4xx/5xx error handling is described here - http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html